# How to kill running program in SBT but stay in console

Tags: scala, sbt

While in sbt, is it possible to kill a process started with the run command but remain in the console?

What I mean is:

```
$ sbt
> run 
...
<ctrl-c> kills the entire environment
```

Is it possible to kill the running process and remain at the sbt prompt? This would save significant time since every sbt restart involves 20 seconds or more. Thanks.

Comment: Try `Ctrl+D` (`Command+D` on Mac).

Comment: @Αλεχει, if the program does not depend on standard input, it won't work.

Comment: There's not really an answer there, other than the implicit equivalent of "it cannot be done". `Ctrl+D` doesn't do the job (other than in `sbt console`) unless multiple changes in your build definition and source code.